# How to make a map selection changing colors in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory

My goal is have a simples screen with a grey map and each button that you click, one different part of the map get painted.

[image]

I try to put the how map in one picture and every time that you hit one button I will make visible one part of the map with colour, like:

[image]
[image]

I'm using ConstraintLayout and I put one image above the other. In the end we should have this: 
[image]

But, When I try to open in my cellphone it get some "OutOfMemory" error, but each picture is like 13-16KB, not to much. 
Before I call this Activity I closed all activity with `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

I make a test and all my java code is commented and my xml is almost all commented, if I have one or two pictures work, but if I put the third one give the error.

I start to thing this is something about the empty space in PNG.

But I'm not sure, any ideas or solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start `allocation tracking` then u will see which methods takes that memory. Memory size of image is not that important. It could scale up and u got a lot of images. `Tint` is that attribute u look for.

Comment: The problem is use tint programmatically, because the only solution that I saw until now is like a filter. Don't work like the tint in .xml

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Profiler (a bottom tab) to see a memory allocation. If your chart increases slowly (maybe up to 100 Mb or more) it won't crash an application.